# Axapta 4.0 comment shortcut

Tags: axapta, x++

I am working now 3 Days with axapta 4.0 and I am not able to comment text by shortcut. I am aware that there is no shortcut implemented in axapta but is there a possible solution so that I can write a snippet or something that comments my text. I can't imagine that nobody else encountered this problem before and hasn't found a solution.

Comment: Do you mean comments for source code? There is the `EditorScripts` class but I'm not sure if it is already available in version 4. Did you take a look at the Axaptapedia [Editor scripts](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Editor_scripts) page?

Comment: It has been available at least since 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you. It's sort of hacked up from other methods just to be copy & paste simple...you can optimize.

Create this method **alex_GeneralComment** here:

> `Classes\EditorScripts\alex_GeneralComment`

And put in this code and you should be able to select code in the editor, `[right click>Scripts>alex>General Comment]`

It will create a comment that looks like this, with the cursor on the `//` line. Experiment with it.

> ```
> // (ALEX) (12/03/2015)
> // 
> //-->
> info("If I select these two lines of code, then right click and do the ");
> info("script, the comment block will look like this");
> //<--
> ```

```
public void alex_GeneralComment(Editor _editor)
{
    #define.YourCompanyName("ALEX")
    str         selText = EditorScripts::getSelectedText(_editor, false);
    str         selFirstLine;
    int         startLine = _editor.selectionStartLine()+1;
    int         endLine   = _editor.selectionEndLine()+1;
    int         startCol  = _editor.selectionStartCol();
    str         name      = XUserInfo::find(False, curUserId()).name ? XUserInfo::find(False, curUserId()).name : XUserInfo::find(False, curUserId()).networkAlias;
    xppSource   xppSource;

    str getSelectedText(Editor e, boolean takeAllIfEmpty = true)
    {
        int i;
        str text;
        str line;
        int _startLine = e.selectionStartLine()+1;
        int _endLine   = e.selectionEndLine()+1;
        int _startCol  = e.selectionStartCol();
        int endCol    = e.selectionEndCol();

        if (_startLine == _endLine && _startCol == endCol)
        {
            // This method returns the selected text, and if the user selects
            // no text, then it returns nothing.  So we want to return the
            // entire code block if the parameter is set
            if (!takeAllIfEmpty)
                return text;

            e.firstLine();
            while (e.moreLines())
            {
                text += e.getLine()+'\r\n';
                e.nextLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.firstSelectedLine();
            for (i = _startLine; i <= _endLine; i++)
            {
                line = e.getLine();
                if (i == _startLine && i == _endLine)
                {
                    line = subStr(line, _startCol, endCol-_startCol);
                }
                else
                if (i == _endLine)
                {
                    line = subStr(line, 1, endCol-1);
                }
                else
                if (i == _startLine)
                {
                    line = strRep(' ', _startCol-1)+subStr(line, _startCol, strLen(line));
                }

                text += line + '\r\n';
                e.nextSelectedLine();
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

    boolean isSelectionNonEmpty(str s)
    {
        // delete all special symbols
        return strLen(strRem(strRem(strRem(s," "),"\n"),"\r"))>0;
    }

    if(isSelectionNonEmpty(selText))
    {
        startLine = _editor.selectionStartLine()+1;
        _editor.firstSelectedLine();
        selFirstLine = _editor.getLine();

        startCol  = strLen(selFirstLine) -strLen(strLTrim(selFirstLine));
        xppSource = new xppSource(startCol);
        _editor.insertLines(strFmt("// ("+#YourCompanyName+") (%1)", date2str(today(), 213, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, DateFlags::None))+"\n");
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("// \n"));
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("//-->\n"));

        // If it's one line, indent it, otherwise paste as-is
        if (startLine == endLine)
            _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent() + selText);
        else
            _editor.insertLines(selText);

        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("//<--"));
        _editor.gotoLine(startLine);
        _editor.gotoCol(strLen(_editor.getLine())); // Go to the comments section
    }
    else
    {
        startCol = _editor.columnNo();
        xppSource = new xppSource(startCol);
        _editor.insertLines(strFmt("// ("+#YourCompanyName+") (%1)", date2str(today(), 213, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, DateFlags::None))+"\n");
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("// \n"));
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("//-->\n"));
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("\n"));
        endLine = _editor.currentLineNo(); // Line we want to end on
        _editor.insertLines(xppSource.indent()+strFmt("//<--"));
        _editor.gotoLine(endLine);
        _editor.gotoCol(startCol+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there the possibility to add a short cut like ctrl+k,c or something like that ?

Comment: In AX2012, yes, you can add a tab-shortcut key, where you can type whatever you want such as `mycom` then press `tab`. See this blog for example where they use this exactly https://workflowax.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/527/ . But in AX 4.0, which is almost 10 years old, maybe not.

Comment: I read the article but it seems it isn't exactly what I meant. I meant the comment function like the one in VS2013 for example. You mark some text and press ctrl+k,c and the marked text will be out commented. But your answer is still nice because this was the other thing that was bothering me. So anyways thank you. If you have some further information regarding the commenting marked text I would appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, for AX 4.0 it doesn't look like it exists. 4.0 is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa865357(v=ax.10).aspx and AX 2012 is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa865357.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081463/2293556) above:

You can open the available editor scripts menu by typing `Alt+R, S`

After that, you could take a look at the `getApplicableScripts` method in the `EditorScripts` class. This method is responsible to fetch the editor scripts which the menu contains by returning a container filled with them. You can modify that code for your needs.

As an example, to modify the container to only contain the comment & uncomment functionality, add following code right underneath the variable declarations:

```
if (curUserId() == "YourUserId")
{
    scripts += "comments_comment";
    scripts += "comments_uncomment";

    return scripts;
}

//- Some more code
```

In that way, you can type `Alt+R, S, C, C` to comment and `Alt+R, S, C, U`.

... it just needs a bit practice to remember at first.